# Git bash uses wrong python, other solutions don't work

Tags: python, git, git-bash

I've seen a couple solution so far but they don't work. I'm trying to run (in git bash, on windows)

```
bash scripts/test.sh
```

But it's supposed to use Python27, and I have that, and Python34. when I type python --version, it tells me it's using Python34. I tried doing

```
PATH=$PATH:/c/Python27/
```

But it still tells me I'm using Python34. I know it's in my environment variables, so what am I missing?

Comment: I get an error: `python2: command not found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$PATH:/c/Python27/` adds `/c/Python27/` *to the end* of your `PATH`. The directory containing the Python34 executable must be already in your `$PATH`. So you need to add `/c/Python27/` *before* the other directories listed in `$PATH`, so it is checked before the directory containing Python34.

```
PATH=/c/Python27/:$PATH
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked! Plus, great explanation, I wish it was provided the first time I ran into that line of code.